# Copying Character array into char array

Tags: java, arrays, character

Hi I want to fast copy array of *Characters* to array of *chars* I can write a method that copies *Character* array into *char* array, by converting every *Charater* in array to *char* but is there any ready method which is faster just as *Arrays.copyOf* for two arrays of same type?

Comment: What about unboxing?

Comment: It surely would work but in that case I would have to create new Char array and just fill it with data from Character array and I'm looking for some ready method that will make that for me

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
    char[] myCharArray = Arrays.stream(myCharacterArray)
            .map(ch -> ch.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining())
            .toCharArray();
```

It was fast to write. Whether it will execute fast? Unless you have a very big array or do this conversion often, you shouldn‘t need to care.

Answer (score 2):

There is method in Apache Commons Lang which does exactly what you need:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive-java.lang.Character:A-

```
public static char[] ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(Character[] array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technical not possible, but you might do with a lazy kind of unboxing Character to char. For instance using a Stream. (Which at the moment might even be additional overhead.)

If the Character array stems from a Collection, a List, then you just might take measures at the source. Though all will not be fast. But an array of Character is not sophisticated, like wrapping every coin in its own piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `Character[]` array

```
Character[] asciiChars = Stream.iterate(32, i -> i += 1)
                         .map(i -> Character.valueOf((char)i.intValue()))
                         .limit(95)
                         .toArray(Character[]::new);
```

A similar `Stream`-based solution to the example above, saving one mapping step, would be:

```
char[] chars = Stream.of(asciiChars)
               .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
               .toString()
               .toCharArray();
```